# vba move email to folder if subject is like?

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I'm using the following code to move emails from my inbox to another folder called Supplier.
It currently works if the subject is 'Introduction' but not if the subject is 'my introduction'

what I want to do is add a line that says if subject or body is LIKE 'introduction' or is Like 'introduce' or Like 'Supply' etc...

Also I have multiple accounts in my outlook, at the moment this code only works for my default account, but I want it to work for my account called 'Purchasing@Hewden.co.uk', is there a way I can change this? my 'supplier' folder is within the inbox of my purchasing@hewden.co.uk account and I want to move the email from this inbox to the supplier folder.

```
Sub MoveItems()
 Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
 Dim myInbox As Outlook.Folder
 Dim myDestFolder As Outlook.Folder
 Dim myItems As Outlook.Items
 Dim myItem As Object


 Set myNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
 Set myInbox = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
 Set myItems = myInbox.Items
 Set myDestFolder = myInbox.Folders("Supplier")
 Set myItem = myItems.Find("[Subject] = 'Introduction'")
 While TypeName(myItem) <> "Nothing"
 myItem.Move myDestFolder
 Set myItem = myItems.FindNext
 Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: You don't need VBA at all.  Create a filter.

Comment: I have tried using a rule but this doesn't do what I want it to, I would prefer to use vba if I can

Comment: What doesn't the rule do that vba has to offer?

Comment: rules won't always read a subject unless it is spelt exact, vba allows you to do an if like subject for instance if the subject contains 'this is an introduction' then vba can pick this up where as a rule won't

Comment: keyword in subject being 'introduction'

Comment: It doesn't have to be exact. You can have a rule that searches for introduction in the subject and sorts from there. What version of outlook are you running?

Comment: you need to use Application.AdvancedSearch and then you can use the keyword Like:  see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866933(v=office.15).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I know that the question asked for code however this can be done much easier through the use of rules. If this answer is not wanted I will delete it.

Anyway you should read up on [this](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/outlook-help/create-a-rule-HP005242897.aspx) and [this](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/outlook-help/manage-email-messages-by-using-rules-HA102749402.aspx) to learn about rules, they are truly awesome.
You're going to want to create a new rule and have it filter based on a keyword within the subject line, you can just write 'introduction' and Outlook will know to look for that word.

You also have to specify where the email goes and, in my case, you also need to specify what kind of notification (if any) is displayed when new mail arrives.

All of this should be available under Rules -> Create New Rule.